# Building embedded system with no reliable internet connection

Tags: ftp, embedded, labview, hamachi, resume-upload

I'm not really sure how to search this over the internet, I tried some searches but never got the help I needed, so I'll just ask here. (sry if it's already answered!)

I'm building a embedded system that runs on windows. I'll gather some data and send over the internet to read at home. I'm most probably using a 3G connection to connect my system (that will keep moving) to the internet and send the data over. I planned to use a ftp server with a hamachi connection to send the files to another pc. And it'll be automated, so the only person action will be to read the data at home. I tested and this all works fine when I use a reliable connection, like when I'm home.

My question is, will it work when my 3G connection drops and how can I make this system reliable? 
I want to keep storing the data if the connection is down and send it all when it's back online, but i don't know if the system will automatically connect (i can't have a person manually clicking 'connect') to hamachi or to the ftp server (my first time using this technologies).

Also, is there a better, more reliable or simpler way than hamachi+ftp to send the data?

Thx,

EDIT: Adding more info. I'm gathering data with a LabView VI. The plan was to save this data into a file (txt, csv or whatever), send the file over and have another VI reading the file and display some graphs and etc. There is a DataSocket in Labview to send some data over the internet, but I'm not familiar with these internet protocols, it says I can use FTP, HTTP and others. What is paid and what can i do for free?

Comment: My search keywords for your scenario would be `hamachi vpn autoconnect` and `ftp resume` probably specialized to `ftp resume upload`. BTW: [evernote](https://evernote.com/)'s mobile client does this background sync split into smaller packets whenever the connection's up. There's also an indicator for the end user showing if it's synced or the user should click the connect if (s)he really wants to read it at home. I'm not sure how exactly they do it (the sync algorithm), but that might be another thing I'd try to _search over the internet_

Comment: Tried to edit and add these tags, but i couldn't add tags with spaces (i suck at this haha)

Comment: I did not mean the search keywords to be used as Stack Overflow tags so that other people can gather around them and read your question. I meant it like that is what I'd use to Google something relevant

Comment: I have used Dropbox for configurations like this. Using a 3G router that automatically connected to the internet, and had an SMS command interface, that allowed me to even perform a WakeOnLan to recover a crash of my PC (your computer is running Windows...), it also had a UPS that rebooted the PC every night.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is there a better, more reliable or simpler way than hamachi+ftp to send the data?

Might it be simpler to use e-mail (SMTP)?  That has the advantage that the sender and receiver need not be up at the same time.

Comment: @xmojmr : The last line asks if there is a "*better, more reliable or simpler*" solution;  if there is then answering the [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is irrelevant.  I am not sure that length of answer is necessarily a measure of quality.  The answer is succinct - there is little more to say.